# How Can I Use an Existing Vector in a :keys Destructuring

Tags: clojure

Currently I have to type them out as a literal list of symbols in a :keys destructing in a let binding.

```
(let [{:keys [title author]} arg-map]
  (println title))
```

But I have a list of the keywords I want to destructure, and I want to use them in other places in the program.

Is there some macro magic I can do to just reference the symbol name in a let binding rather than have to duplicate the existing vector, making me have to update the same list multiple times if it changes.

```
(def valid-keys [:title :author])

(let [{:keys valid-keys} arg-map]
  (println title))
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does your arg-map look like?  To clarify, you want to be able to cherry-pick which keys you want and return their values?  Have you used the core `key` or `value` in any of your attempts?

Comment: In you're example, you're not using all of the values in `arg-map`; you're only using `title`, so you can just use `{:keys [title]}` to destructure it. Plus, that makes it clearer where exactly `title` comes from.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely

```
(def keywords [:title :author])

(defmacro with-valid-keys [m & forms]
  (let [syms (map (comp symbol name) keywords)]
    `(let [{:keys [~@syms]} ~m]
       ~@forms)))
```

If you have a vector of keywords, you can easily convert those to symbols and use them in a let binding. From the macroexpand you can see that the macro just produces the let binding with symbols.

```
(prn
  (macroexpand-1 '(with-valid-keys {:title "hahaha"}
                                   (println title))))
```

=> (clojure.core/let [{:keys [title author]} {:title "hahaha"}] (println title))

```
(with-valid-keys
  {:title "hahaha"}
  (println title))
```

=> hahaha

Be wary that hiding bindings like this introduces some problems:

1. Shadowing. Say you had a 'valid key' :name, but then in your code you used the `name` function from inside `with-valid-keys`, you would get the bound value of name, not the function.
2. Navigability. IDEs wont be able to identify where the symbol comes from.